# Scale image for ImageButton and then center it

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

What I want to do:

```
    final ImageButtonStyle upStyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
    upStyle.up = spriteUp;
    upStyle.down = spriteDown;
    upStyle.imageUp = spriteIcon;

    imgButton = new ImageButton(upStyle);
    imgButton.getImage().setScale(0.5f);
```

However, this produces the following result: [image: White box is the button background, circle with a '2' is the image]

This is what I want:
[image: The image is centered]

In order to achieve this right now I have to call this code:

```
float scale = 0.5f;
imgButton.pack();
imgButton.getImage().setOrigin(imgButton.getImage().getWidth() * scale, imgButton.getImage().getHeight() * scale);
```

Things I've tried to play around with to no result (in no particular order):

```
imgButton.getImage().setAlign(Align.center);
imgButton.invalidate();
imgButton.pack();
imgButton.getImageCell().align(Align.center);
```

Any ideas, maybe some screwing around with the cell properties? Nothing seems to be changing anything unless I change the Origin manually and repack...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
imgButton.getImage().setOrigin(Align.center);
imgButton.getImage().setScale(0.5f);
```

Instead of doing the trick width width and height * 0.5f and using that as origin LibGDX has a nice way of specifying the center with Align.center.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked in the end:

```
    final ImageButtonStyle upStyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
    upStyle.up = spriteUp;
    upStyle.down = spriteDown;
    upStyle.imageUp = spriteIcon;
    imgButton = new ImageButton(upStyle);

    final float scale = 0.5f;
    imgButton.getImage().setScale(scale);

    // Calling any of these works.
    imgButton.pack();
    imgButton.layout();
    imgButton.validate();

    // Calling these doesn't work.
    imgButton.invalidate();
    imgButton.invalidateHierarchy();

    // Has to be called after either pack(), layout(), or validate() are called.
    imgButton.getImage().setOrigin(Align.center);

    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(500, 700));
    stage.addActor(imgButton);
```

I don't understand why I have to call either of pack(), layout(), or validate() after setting the scale... But after trying many combinations I found this to work. Maybe someone could give some deeper insight on why this works the way it is and maybe if there's a better way?

Ideally what I would like to do is something like this:

```
final float scale = 0.5f;
imgButton.getImage().setScale(scale);
imgButton.getImage().setOrigin(Align.center);

// or
final float scale = 0.5f;
imgButton.getImage().setScale(scale);
imgButton.getImage().setOrigin(Align.center);
imgButton.pack();   // Forcing a pack / invalidate I can live with.
```

Comment: Also given that the Image is being added to Button's table, shouldn't the positioning/placement of the image be controlled by the cell properties? I've tried doing it with cells but didn't get anywhere. I'd expect this: "imgButton.getImageCell().align(Align.center);" to behave in that manner.